# Class header files

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio

main.cpp

```
int main()
{
return 0;
}
```

cell.h

```
#pragma once

class _cell {};
```

cell.cpp

```
#include "cell.h"
```

experiment.h

```
#pragma once

class _experiment
{
_cell cell;
};
```

experiment.cpp

```
#include "experiment.h"
#include "cell.h"
```

Error:

```
experiment.h(5): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'cell'
experiment.h(5): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
experiment.h(5): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
```

This has been driving me nuts. Any help? Thanks!

Comment: Generally you only expect to see symbols defined by the compiler to begin with underscore.

Comment: I always use _type for types. Thanks for the tip, will try to use something else from now on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to `#include <cell.h>` from `experiment.h` as otherwise `_cell` is not defined when used in `experiment.h`.

Answer (score 1):

Move the include from cell.cpp to the .h

.h:

```
#pragma once
#include "cell.h"

class _experiment
{
_cell cell;
};
```

.cpp:

```
#include "experiment.h"
```

Classes need the definition of members to contain instances of them.

Comment: I moved all the includes from cpp files to header files. Then found the problem. I had a "common.h", which included "cell.h", but in "cell.h" I also included "common.h". So I had kind of a loop in includes. Works perfectly now. Thanks!

Comment: @user1092682 [Article that could be helpful to read](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_dependency)